# Task Exception not caught

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, task-parallel-library

With the following code I only catch the exceptions in the ContinueWith action and not with the try-catch block. Does anyone have an idea why I can't catch with try-catch? As I understand the ContinueWith is the old way of exception handling with tasks and that with .Net Core 3 the exceptions are also catchable with try-catch.

```
try
{
    await Socket.ConnectAsync(endpoint)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            // Works
            throw task.Exception;
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // Doesn't work
    throw;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ae)
{
    // Doesn't work
    throw;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Doesn't work
    throw;
}
```

The Socket.ConnectAsync is from the [SocketTaskExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.connectasync?view=netcore-3.0#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_ConnectAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_System_Net_EndPoint_) class

**Edit 1:**
I narrowed the problem down to the Socket Extension method from Microsoft:

```
public static Task ConnectAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint remoteEP)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            (targetEndPoint, callback, state) => ((Socket)state).BeginConnect(targetEndPoint, callback, state),
            asyncResult => ((Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState).EndConnect(asyncResult),
            remoteEP,
            state: socket);
    }
```

This implementation causes the Exceptions to not be catched. I have no idea though how to make the Task.Factory to throw the exceptions.

Comment: What do you expect from doing both? If you catch an exception, it won't trigger the catch block of an enclosing try/catch unless you rethrow.

Comment: doesn't matter if I do try-catch without the ContinueWith. Only the try-catch also doesn't catch

Comment: Ah. That wasn't clear to me.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I added the throw in the ContinueWith

Comment: This rogue `throw` inside the `ContinueWith` delegate causes a compile-time exception: `Error CS0156 A throw statement with no arguments is not allowed outside of a catch clause`

Comment: `ContinueWith is the old way of exception handling with tasks and that with .Net Core 3 the exceptions are also catchable with try-catch` - technically true, but the old way was .NET 4.0 era (2010), and could be considered outdated with the introduction of `await` in .NET 4.5 (2012). .NET Core 3.0 (2019) doesn't change this; it still uses `await` just the same as the last seven years.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like the only problem was the debugger settings. I've reset the settings and disabled "Just my Code" and now it works